# How to wire a PPTC polyswitch + blown indicator LED to protect a bi-directional DC motor from stalling?

Tags: led, dc-motor, reverse-polarity, polyfuse

I have the following setup and it works well as is, except that I would like to protect the 12V DC motors (Reverse High Torque Permanent Magnet 12V DC motor) with a PPTC polyswitch + a LED to indicate a temporary overheating/blown state to the user.

[image]

I understand that by simply inserting the PPTC along the positive wire that goes to the DC motor will work.  Tough, I would like some advice on how to additionally connect a 12V LED (1W) to that circuit.

[image]

Comment: You haven’t said what you want the LED to indicate. And you haven’t linked the data sheet of the polyswitch.

Comment: Uhm, yes I did? In the very first sentence? "+ a LED to indicate a temporary overheating/blown state to the user." / Also, for the datasheet, I guess just typing "JK30 400" in Google yields it? https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/565885/UNSEMI/JK30-400/217/1/JK30-400.html

Comment: I guess it was the *how to additionally connect* sentence that threw me. Are you happy that the forward volt drop of the polyfuse is acceptable for the motor in normal running. Wire the LED across the polyfuse if it has the correct rating for 12 volts and current limiting built in. Also add a reverse protection diode across the LED.

Comment: "Are you" Yes.  This DC motor (as you can see above) has a variable speed controlled by the user.  That DC motor is rated for anything between 6V-12V.  The voltage drop only means the motor will turn a little slower, but this is not critical.  If I connect the LED across the polyfuse, then how will the circuit make a closed loop? I don't understand how this can work, since the PPTC is in series only on the positive wire.  See above? Did you also read that the DC motor is bi-directional? So the red wire sometimes is negative, sometimes positive.

Comment: Use a bridge rectifier to feed the LED. The closed loop comes from the low dc resistance of the motor.

Comment: Can you draw what you're discussing and put it in an answer?

Comment: 1W is quite a bright LED.

Comment: Yes, it's super bright.  (Also it's 12V, not 5V, so it's still "just" 83mA).

Comment: @that-ben did you understand my answer (despite the lack of a diagram)?

Comment: @Andyaka It's been 4 years, man! That robot has been mowing the lawn for a while by now.  There was no need for that polyswitch nor its LED in the end.  Nothing ever blown on that robot :) I did not really understand the explanation.  Over 4 years, I would have thought that you had finally got to MS Paint to do some sort of drawing, though?

Answer (score 2):

Use a bridge rectifier to feed the LED. The closed loop comes from the low dc resistance of the motor. – Andy aka

> Can you draw what you're discussing and put it in an answer?

Unfortunately I have no drawing facilities at the moment so I’ll try and describe...

Treat the voltage across the polyfuse as AC. Connect the polyfuse terminals to the AC terminals of a bridge rectifier. Connect the appropriate LED to the DC output of the bridge rectifier.

The LED you have chosen ought to be able to work down to 9 volts but, if it can’t then use a regular LED in series with a resistor.